# Migration on .netcore app which uses always encrypted and elastic scale

Tags: .net-core, always-encrypted, azure-elastic-scale

Our platform uses elastic scale and always encrypted.
Now we migrated to .netcore
As I understood, always encrypted on .netcore supported by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient which contains copies of classes that support always encrypted. But Elastic scale operates types from System.Data.SqlClient which are not supported encrypted on .netcore.
So I have next questions:

1. Is my vision is right or wrong?
2. Does (Will) exist version of Elastic pool which work with types from Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?
3. What about some work arounds?

Thanks!
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is already an open issue https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/issues/203 related to this. You can follow up there.